# Dropwizard 0.8.1 : multiple file upload

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard and I want to upload multiple files at once.

How could I change my code to upload multiple files?

I'm using `org.glassfish.jersey.media', 'jersey-media-multipart', '2.17'`
 for file upload.

Here is my code for a single file upload :

```
@Path("/uploadPhoto")
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Upload a photo for an Ad",
        response = Response.class)
@POST
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response fileUploaded(@FormDataParam("file") final InputStream inputStream,
                         @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
    List<AdImage> images = new ArrayList<AdImage>();

        images.add(writeImageAndSave(inputStream
                , contentDispositionHeader));
    return Response.ok(toJson(images), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it here is the code :

```
    @Path("/uploadPhoto")
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Upload a photo for an Ad",
        response = Response.class)
@POST
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {


    List<AdImage> images = new ArrayList<AdImage>();
    List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts =
            multiPart.getFields("file");
    for (FormDataBodyPart part : bodyParts) {
        images.add(writeImageAndSave(part.getValueAs(InputStream.class
        ), part.getFormDataContentDisposition()));
    }

    return Response.ok(toJson(images), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

Comment: Do you or someone else know how to do the same without FormDataMultiPart? FormDataMultiPart includes that there is a HTML Form, but in some cases for machine to machine, there is not form. Perhaps sth like this --> uploadFile(InputStream[] inStream)

Comment: @heaphach this may be useful in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075646/uploading-a-file-in-jersey-without-using-multipart

Comment: Thx, but this is just for one file. What I need is sth for multiple files, but without html form :-)